# How can I differentiate this function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I am stuck with this problem, please help me.

I have to differentiate the function:

$y = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} (\ln {x} - \frac{1}{n+1})$

The solution is $x^n \ln{x}$.

I just can't understand the process of getting the solution.

Comment: What was the process?  I'd just use the product rule.  That assumes I know what $d\ln x/dx$ is though.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the product rule:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)\cdot\left(\ln x - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) + \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln x - \frac{1}{n+1}\right).$$